# DataSource.getConnection() in EBJ3 session bean

Tags: java, datasource, ejb-3.0

In using a EJB3 stateless session bean, where is the best place to get an injected DataSource connection?  I had the method calling ds.getConnection(), but this is happening each time, so opening and closing the connection for each call isn't very economical or smart.

Is it generally best to put the accessing and closing of a datasource connection in one of the managed lifecycle methods?  I want to ensure the least costly accessing of the datasource possible, while ensuring the connection is closed when no longer needed so it's not just hanging open.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The Lifecycle of a Stateless Session Bean**
>
> Because a stateless session bean is never passivated, its lifecycle
>   has only two stages: nonexistent and ready for the invocation of
>   business methods. Figure 22-4 illustrates the stages of a stateless
>   session bean.
>
> [image: Diagram showing the lifecycle of a stateless session bean.]
>
> The EJB container typically creates and maintains a pool of stateless
>   session beans, beginning the stateless session bean’s lifecycle. The
>   container performs any dependency injection and then invokes the
>   method annotated @PostConstruct, if it exists. The bean is now ready
>   to have its business methods invoked by a client.
>
> At the end of the lifecycle, the EJB container calls the method
>   annotated @PreDestroy, if it exists. The bean’s instance is then ready
>   for garbage collection.
>
> Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giplj.html

Create a field in the EJB to store the Connection instance, that you get at the @PostConstruct, then release it the @PreDestroy

Here, written code example of this http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java-ee/ejb3/session-beans/slsb/stateless-session-beans-lifecycle-callback-methods/

Comment: If this solved your issue, would you kindly accept this answer as the solution?